# How to disable copy/paste on OSX

Tags: macos, copy-paste

Is it possible to disable the copy-paste feature? I would prefer system-wide, but a solution for a single application would be a good start.

Comment: Can you tell us what you're trying to prevent? There may be other solutions for that.

Comment: I'm trying to prevent myself from using it ;) btw, I'd also be interested in a tool that counts the Cmd-C usages.

Comment: If the problem is that you occasionally drag/drop something accidentally, understand that if you immediately do Cmd-Z (Ctrl-Z on Windows) it will "undo" your last action (and repeating Cmd-Z several times will undo the last several actions, up to a point).  This has rescued me many times.  Cmd-Z works in most programs that support copy/paste.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might also disable the pboard process:

```
launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.pboard.plist
```

After quitting and reopening applications, pasting should stop working in most contexts. It also makes drag and drop and many services stop working.

You can undo the changes by replacing `unload` with `load` or by editing `/var/db/launchd.db/com.apple.launchd.peruser.$UID/overrides.plist`.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you are trying to do, you might use a background process that resets the clipboard periodically. For example save this plist as `~/Library/LaunchAgents/disablecopypaste.plist`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC -//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN
http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd>
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <true/>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>disablecopypaste</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>osascript</string>
        <string>-e</string>
        <string>repeat
set the clipboard to ""
delay 1
end repeat</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Then load it with `launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/disablecopypaste.plist` or by logging out and back in